# ViewController Containment - Child ViewController not sizing correctly in Landscape

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, landscape

The app is set to only support landscape mode.

The custom `UIViewController` has the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MBMainViewController *mainViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MBMainViewController"];

    [self addChildViewController:mainViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:mainViewController.view];
    [mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.mainViewController = mainViewController;
}
```

When app is launched, the frame for the view of the child viewcontroller (`mainViewController`) is still set to the dimension of a portrait.

Is there something I'm missing so the right frame size is set on the child viewcontroller's view?

Answer (score 1):

This apparently only happens to UIViewController that are instantiated from storyboard. In this case, it only works if we set the `autoresizingMask` of the view belonging to the child view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MBMainViewController *mainViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MBMainViewController"];

// Set the autoresizingMask as a fix
    mainViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;


    [self addChildViewController:mainViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:mainViewController.view];
    [mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.mainViewController = mainViewController;
}
```

My guess is that when you instantiate a view controller from the storyboard, the constraints have already been set or that it doesn't come with the right autoresizingMask values.